# UlanBaator to Irkut

Tags: visas, russia, argentinian-citizens

I want to go from UBator to Irkut in August.

I have a passport from Argentina. It lets me enter Russia visa free. Would I be able to cross the border and allowed to ride the train all the way to Vladivostok? Or is visa free entry only valid through major Russian international airports and only in some parts of the Russian territory?

Answer (score 3):

With an Argentina passport [you may enter Russia visa free](https://argentina.mid.ru/es/vizovye-voprosy) for 90 days of every 180 days. The mode of transport and port of entry are not relevant. You can go by plane, train, car, walking, horseback...

> (ES) Los Nacionales del Estado de una de las Partes, titulares de las pasaportes validos (con excepción de los pasaportes diplomáticos, oficiales y de servicio), que habiliten el cruce de la frontera, (en adelante "los pasaportes") podrán entrar, salir, pasar el transito y permanecer en el territorio del Estado de la otra parte sin visas hasta noventa (90) dias en cada periodo de ciento ochenta dias a partir de la fecha de la primera entrada.
>
> (EN) Citizens of any of the States, holders of valid passports (except diplomatic, official or service passports), may enter, leave, transit and remain in the territory of the other State without visas for up to ninety days, in each period of one hundred and eighty days since the first entry.